# Show array identification numbers in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have problem with function. Its posible to show and "auto count" all arrays?
My code:

```
$mrJackMaker = 'mrjack';

$aromatyMrJack = array(
    'Arbuz' => $mrJackMaker.'1',
    'Banan'=> $mrJackMaker.'2',
    'Czarna porzeczka'=> $mrJackMaker.'3'
);

foreach($aromatyMrJack as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key." ". $value . "<br>";
}
```

How write this code to get:

- Arbuz mrjack1
- Banan mrjack2
- Czarna porzeczka mrjack3

With auto count values, 1, 2, 3... etc. Pls help.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Please include your code in the question instead of linking to an external page.

Comment: here is demo: http://katalogliquidow.mrqzi.webd.pl/form_test.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple solution.

```
<?php

    $mrJackMaker = 'mrjack-';
    $arr = array(
               'Arbuz' => $mrJackMaker,
               'Banan'=> $mrJackMaker,
               'Czarna porzeczka'=> $mrJackMaker,
               'Czarna '=> $mrJackMaker
            );

    $i = 0;

    foreach($arr as $key => $value)
    {
        $i++;
        echo "Key is: ".$key." value is: ". $value.$i."<br>";
    }
```

Output is something link this:

```
Key is: Arbuz value is: mrjack-1
Key is: Banan value is: mrjack-2
Key is: Czarna porzeczka value is: mrjack-3
Key is: Czarna value is: mrjack-4
```

Hope its fulfill your requirement!

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: You'r most welcome friend @Thomasz. Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually by using a non-associative array, the *key* (in the [*foreach*](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)) can be a numeric value that can be used (`$index` in the code below) that can be used instead of incrementing a counter.

```
<?php

$suffix = 'mrjack-';
$names = array(
           'Arbuz',
           'Banan',
           'Czarna porzeczka'
        );
$listItems = array();
foreach($names as $index => $name)  {
    $listItems[] = $name.' '.$suffix.($index+1);
}
echo '<ul><li>'.implode('</li><li>', $listItems).'</li></ul>';
```

See a demonstration of this [here](https://www.tehplayground.com/xJKvPR9VOuIKTz7r).

And it could be done in a *functional* programming way, using [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
<?php

$suffix = 'mrjack-';
$names = array(
           'Arbuz',
           'Banan',
           'Czarna porzeczka'
        );
$listItems = array_map(function($name, $index) {
    return $name.' '.$suffix.($index+1);
}, array_values($names), array_keys($names));
echo '<ul><li>'.implode('</li><li>', $listItems).'</li></ul>';
```

See a demonstration of this [here](https://www.tehplayground.com/iaMu5l13eY2EvteT).